# Why was the Apollo 6 service module painted white?

Tags: apollo-program

All other SM's were silver except Apollo 6. I'm wondering what the justification for this was, if any?

Comment: Possibly just for aesthetics! Wikipedia says “the SM was painted white to match the Command Module's appearance,” but it’s unclear what the source for that is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module#Service_Module

Comment: It may have been part of the reassembly between the SM and CM.  The CM of CSM-14 was disassembled as part of the investigation for the Apollo 1 fire, and the SM was later reassembled with a different CM for Apollo 6 (After that SM was destroyed in an explosion!)

Comment: All the Block I modules were painted white.  Only the Skylab modules in Block II used white paint, because of the longer duration.

Comment: @amI: Apollo 4 used a Block I CSM... with a silver SM.

Comment: @Sean - I was wrong.  The change came before block II.  Apollo 6 SM was older (014) than Apollo 4 SM (017) because SM 020 was destroyed as noted above so Apollo 6 used the Apollo 1 SM.

Comment: @aml what happened to SM 020?

Comment: @JustinBraun it launched on Apollo 4: Based on [this page](http://www.friends-partners.org/mwade/craft/csmlocki.htm) it seems that SM-017 had the propellant tank failure (1966 Oct 25). [This document](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/CSM27_CSM_Contract_pp257-264.pdf) confirms that and further states that Apollo 4 was CM-017/SM-020 and Apollo 6 was CM-020/SM-014; CM-014 was modified to CM-014A and used for a land test at MSC (Johnson Space Center, Houston); all these CM and SM are Block I.

Comment: [One section of the Wikipedia article mentioned above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_command_and_service_module#CSMs_produced) had errors; I've updated it with correct info for CMs and SMs -014, -017, and -020.